# Proper way to fill a struct with 0 using std::fill?

Tags: c++

Does `std::fill` designed for fill struct as well?
For example I got a struct:

```
struct Foo {
  int i = 1;
  float f = 0.2;
};
```

for some reason I want to fill the `Foo` with `0`:

```
int main() {
  Foo foo;
//  memset(&foo, 0, sizeof(Foo));
  std::fill(&foo, &foo + 1, 0);
  std::cout << foo.i << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo.f << std::endl;
}
```

but the compilation failed:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Foo’ and ‘const int’)
```

Am I using `std::fill` in a wrong way?

P.S. I found that if I change to

```
std::fill((uint8_t*)&foo, (uint8_t*)&foo + sizeof(foo), 0);
```

the code will work, does that mean if `std::fill` is dealing with a struct type, it must find a corresponding iterator class?

Comment: Simplest thing would be `Foo foo = {}`

Comment: @TonyTannous - That won't do. The default member initializers will be used.

Comment: @TonyTannous, no, that will set all fields with default values, which is not 0 in my case.

Comment: Cast the pointers as `char`, and for the end "iterator" add the `sizeof` of the structure.

Comment: The float member is what makes this tricky. ISO C++ doesn't specify many constraints on the floating point representation used by the implementation. An all zero bit pattern may in fact not be a "zero" float.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, yeah, this example is not very appropriate as there's a floating point field, I'm considering whether change it or not.

Comment: What's wrong with `memset`? It's not like you're making use of the type-safety `std::fill` offers.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, nothing wrong with `memset`, and you are right about the type-safety. It's just because I though `std::fill` do the same thing as `memset` before, which seems not exactly the same.

Comment: @ravenisadesk I checked what my standard library does with `std::fill`. It checks if it's safe to do `memset` at compile-time, calls `memset` if that's the case and does a plain for-loop otherwise.

Comment: @ravenisadesk I checked VisualStudio's https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f4c5792b2be4f56b4130817803ca21f7a3ee8f4/stl/inc/xutility#L4394

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, I checked the source code again and I'm wrong, the Gcc library will also check if the address is contiguous. But I'm confused that the code do not say what to do if the address is not contiguous, I'm not very clear why they write like this: https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h.html, line 706

Comment: @ravenisadesk it calls `__fill_a`, which seems to be specialized on line `690` for types-that can be safely `memset`ed.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, it seems that they only check if type is byte size, checked the address contiguous on runtime. As my understanding the if statement could have false branch?

Comment: @ravenisadesk note that the specialization that uses `memset` takes pointers, not just any iterators. So it's not possible for the range to be incontiguous. If it were, we'd be using some custom iterator classes, and some other version of the function would be called.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, I got you point, the code gives me a feeling that the writer think if you passed a pointer, than you intend is to fill a contiguous data, if the address is not, I'll do nothing, right?

Comment: @ravenisadesk That's correct as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the compiler told you, `std::fill` uses `operator=` internally. If you define it in your class, you can use `std::fill` with it.

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

> Assigns the given value to the elements in the range [first, last).

Assignement means the `operator=`.

Comment: So it seems that my understanding of `std::fill` is not an alternative to `memset` is wrong? I'v thought that `std::fill` will call `memset` somehow.

Comment: No, it will assign the value you specified to every element using the `operator=`. See the link I provided, there's even a possible implementation, which is working and fully compliant.

Comment: Memset is a low-level, C-style way of doing things. You generally should not need its capabilities unless, you're really doing something low level, like composing instructions to some hardware device.

Answer (score 3):

Try filling it with explicit values: `foo = Foo { 0, 0 };`.

Comment: @ravenisadesk - An answer/question should not be cluttered with with "Edit:" related noise. It should contain just the pertinent information, and be the best version of itself. Comments that are no longer relevant need to be deleted. There's even a designated comment flag for it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That would be very nice if all participants noticed that what they comment earlier has edit. In the real world it's hard for a third person to figure out whether the comment is out-of-date or not if the original participant do not delete the old comment. I appreciate your contributes to this community but just can't agree with you.

Comment: @ravenisadesk - You know you can delete your own comments when they no longer apply, right? It would have have been less effort to do, than ask Christopher to do idiosyncratic editing. It's not just my opinion, it's the consensus since comments have been introduced, and is in fact "the real world" on SO. Don't get too attached to comments, because they can easily go away.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, Yes, in this case, but what if I forget to delete the comment, some guys who not familiar with this case maybe confused: who's right? This will lead the answerer's nice answer be uncertain to somebody. I think I'm just trying to be nice to give some advise, but, yeah, this is just my opinion.

Comment: @ravenisadesk - Typically, one of several things happens. (1) They ping me. I see the edit happened, I delete my comment and flag theirs for deletion as no longer needed. (2) They figure it out themselves, flag my comment as no longer needed. (3) They ping the poster of the question/answer, and that person then flags the relevant comments.... Either way, if a comment is confusing and no longer relevant, it should just go. That is far more streamlined then making folks follow some sort of timeline to understand a conversation that is no longer relevant.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, well after all these year I feel that I still can't get well with this community, still, appreciate your contribute, I've already deleted my profile, good bye.

Comment: explicitly list all the values is exactly what you try to avoid here..

Comment: There is no shorthand because the values are of different types.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the design purpose of `std::fill` is not the same with `memset`.

The references emphasize the word "element", so the purpose of `std::fill` is to iterate all elements and set the desired value, no matter the elements are contiguous in memory or not, the suggested implementation which uses for statement prove this.

As for `memset`, it seems that it only focus on contiguous data in memory.